# How to make newly added main menu option in magento admin section "selected"

Tags: magento

I have developed a new custom extension for magento admin section. Main menu option of this extension in admin section is visible. When I click on that menu option, functionality of this extension is working as per development/expected. But on this menu option "active" class is not being applied ( so that user can differentiate other menu option with this selected menu  ).

There is no submenu under this main menu option. How can I apply "active" class on that menu option when this is clicked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_setActiveMenu($menuPath)` method.
For more details you can check `Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_PageController::_initAction()`.